# "track bunches", "distant understudies" and "grown-ups"

Tags: sentence-meaning

This sentence is used in the context of pedagogy and here is it:

> Distance education focuses on track bunches with extraordinary attributes and inescapable learning needs (grown-ups and deep-rooted learning, distant understudies).

Could you explain please this sentence in easier words and provide the explanation of such words as track bunches, distant understudies and grown-ups?

Comment: I think your text is not well written. Don't copy it. To my mind, only a non-native speaker would be likely to have written "inescapable learning needs" (whatever that means).

Comment: I took it from the book about distance education, it is like a science article, that is why it cannot be written badly.

Comment: It doesn't look remotely like "English" to me. Please provide more details about the source.

Comment: There are about 4 pages and I am making a translation from English and, to be honest, I do not understand a great number of words there.

Comment: If you say you're translating something ***from*** English, I'm afraid you've got a real problem here! I think there is no chance that the text you've cited was *written* by a native Anglophone, so I can only assume it's a bad translation to start with. Presumably it's "translated" from some language other than your own, because if it *was* produced by someone who thinks in the same language as you, you'd probably understand what it was intended to mean better than me!

Comment: Hope I will cope with that! Thank you anyway!

Comment: This question is about some technical jargon in Education.  Even though I'm fairly familar with this jargon, I've no idea what this means.  So this question is beyond "English Learning".  It is not about English, as it is understood by the vast majority of English speakers. It needs a specialist translator.  This task is beyond us.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this specialist terminology is beyond the scope of English *Learning*.

Comment: "inescapable learning needs" would probably be better as something like "essential learning needs" - you shouldn't want to escape from learning stuff. I can find a few examples of "track bunches" as a noun phrase, but none is applicable: cyclists bunched together on a track; proton tracks bunched in a measurement; a music track called "Bunches".

Comment: A "track" in education normally refers to [setting](https://educationendowmentfoundation.org.uk/education-evidence/teaching-learning-toolkit/setting-and-streaming) i.e. grouping by ability. My best guess would be "track bunching" refers to students either within a track or in separate tracks bunching into groups with similar performance, rather than individual outliers. But not sure if that fits - is distance learning better suited to groups or individuals?

Answer (score -1):

The main point of this sentence is to inform the readers on what distance education(during this COVID-19 some safety measures,e.g. social distancing are implemented while learning)
requires.”Track Brunches” probably means the classification.It is probably a metaphor used to mean classification.Distant under-studies means that studying away from a designated place(likely at home).Grown-ups means adults.

Comment: It is "track **bunches**" in the original sentence, not "track *brunches*". Also we expect answers to be substantiated and backed up by research, so speculative "probably means" is not good enough. However, the original sentence is not good English, so understandably its meaning is hard to decipher.

Comment: @Eddie Kai true so it was a bit hard for me to decipher the sentence